# Matplotlib scatter plot legend, as separate image

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am using `ax.scatter(x,y,c=color, s=size, marker='*', label="mylabel")` to plot 4 symbols in a scatter plot (markers are `','`, `'o'`,`'*'`, and `'^'`) each with differing sizes and colors.

I have tried calling `ax.legend()` and, although I get the expected label information, none of the markers appear in the legend. I attempted using a number of variations explained here with no avail: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Furthermore, I ultimately need my legend to be in a completely separate image. I have tried:
[Get legend as a separate picture in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534480/get-legend-as-a-separate-picture-in-matplotlib)

and

https://pymorton.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/creating-separate-legend-figure-with-matplotlib/

but haven't been able to display the markers. Any advice would be appreciated!

Here is my plotting code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

lat = np.random.randint(-60.5, high=60.5, size=257087)
lon = np.random.randint(-179.95, high=180, size=257087)
thiscategory =  np.random.randint(12, 60, size=257087)

percRange = np.arange(100,40,-1)


#Rank all values
allPercent=stats.rankdata(thiscategory)/len(thiscategory)

h=np.where(allPercent > 0.9)
hl=np.where((allPercent <= 0.9) & (allPercent > 0.8))
mh=np.where((allPercent <= 0.8) & (allPercent > 0.7))
ml=np.where((allPercent <= 0.7) & (allPercent > 0.6))
l=np.where(allPercent <= 0.6)

allPercent[h]=0
allPercent[hl]=0.25
allPercent[mh]=0.5
allPercent[ml]=0.75
allPercent[l]=1


fig = plt.figure(dpi=400)
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1]) #position: left, bottom, width, height
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('none')

latcorners = ([-90.0,90.0])
loncorners = ([-180.0,180.0])


rgba_low=colors.hex2color('#e0ffff') #224-255-255 Light Cyan
rgba_ml=colors.hex2color('#afeeee') #175-238-238 Pale Turquoise
rgba_mh=colors.hex2color('#ffff00') #Yellow 
rgba_hl=colors.hex2color('#ffa500')  #Orange
rgba_high=colors.hex2color('#f8f8ff') #ghost white

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=latcorners[0],urcrnrlat=latcorners[1],llcrnrlon=loncorners[0],urcrnrlon=loncorners[1])                       
# Draw on map.
x, y = m(lon, lat)



ax.scatter(x[ml],y[ml], c=rgba_ml, s=3, marker=',',edgecolor='none', alpha=0.4, label=str(mlmin)+" to "+str(mlmax))
ax.scatter(x[mh],y[mh], c=rgba_mh, s=5, marker='o', edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5, label=str(mhmin)+" to "+str(mhmax))
ax.scatter(x[hl],y[hl], c=rgba_hl, s=10, marker='*',edgecolor='none', alpha=0.6, label=str(hlmin)+" to "+str(hlmax))
ax.scatter(x[h],y[h], c=rgba_high, s=20, marker='^', edgecolor='none',alpha=0.7, label=str(hmin)+" to "+str(hmax))

ax.set_xlim([-180,180])
ax.set_ylim([-90,90])

#this is where my legend calls were going, but since I want them in a new plot it doesn't seem appropriate


fig.savefig('testfig.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, pad_inches=0)
```

*edited to show sample code.

Comment: This is like calling someone, saying "My computer isn't working". There are simply too many possible things that could have gone wrong. Therefore, you need to post the code that you have used in order to get any help on this issue. The way you describe it, is expected to work, so there must be some problem somewhere in the code that we can only help you with when getting a [MCVE].

Comment: I wanted to keep this open ended in case there was a scatter plot property that I wasn't aware of. I will edit to post the plotting code.

Comment: When I add `ax.legend()` the legend, including the markers, is shown. Since you do not apply any of the commands mentioned in [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534480/get-legend-as-a-separate-picture-in-matplotlib) about producing a legend in a separate file, why do you expect that to happen? Finally, please think about what the words minimal, complete and verifiable stand for in [MCVE]!

Comment: Alright then, in the hopes of keeping the code above minimal and as complete as I could, I removed all of my attempts. But here you go:   
    `handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`
    `ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='lower center',fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)` is what I started with, which gave me a pretty box with my labels but no symbols. Actually, looking closely at that I see a couple of faint symbols, repeated three times before the label.

Comment: After all, the above is not what I wanted (since I wanted a different figure), so following the second and third links I tried `fig = plt.figure()
fig_legend = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 1.25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig_legend.legend(handles, labels, loc='center', frameon=False)
plt.show()` which gave me an empty plot with x,y axis.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what i found:
I had to modify the code I found to not include a figure call. After plotting the scatter (ax.scatter) I called:

```
handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

After plotting the main plot and closing the figure I called a new figure:

```
fig_legend = plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
axi = fig_legend.add_subplot(111)            
fig_legend.legend(handles, labels, loc='center', scatterpoints = 1)
axi.xaxis.set_visible(False)
axi.yaxis.set_visible(False)
fig_legend.canvas.draw()
fig_legend.show()
```

The final results contains two black borders, but it is a separate image and has a single instance of the scatter symbol in the correct color.[legend image example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZWo9.jpg)