# Matplotlib: Convert the legend to a bitmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the legend as a separate bitmap, is that possible with matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
axes.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], 'r')
legend = axes.legend()
```

How would I save legend to bitmap? Any ideas?

Comment: do you want the legend in a separate figure?

Comment: yes that's right, if it were in a separate figure, then I would be able to save it to a bitmap. Good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a legend in a different figure, you can use [`axes.get_legend_handles_labels()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html) to get the legend handles and labels and add them to a different figure.

Also you need to provide a legend in the first plot, using the `label` argument, or to explicitly provide a list of labels to associate with the handles.

The following code should do what I suggested in my comment to the question:

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
axes.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], 'r', label='test')
legend = axes.legend()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111)
# add the legend from a different axes
ax.legend(*axes.get_legend_handles_labels())
# hide the spines and the x/y labels
ax.axis('off')
```

If you want more control for hiding stuff you can hide the axis spines only with

```
ax.set_frame_on(False)
```

or the x/y labels with

```
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the figure itself? and only show the legend? Sorry by figure I mean the axes

Comment: @Har: check my edit

Comment: If none of the answers to [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534480/get-legend-as-a-separate-picture-in-matplotlib) show the method used here, I would suggest you write your answer there, not here, such that people find all options in one place.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: done.