# Seaborn Heatmap: How to move colorbar on bottom of the plot

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to plot colorbar on the bottom of the heatmap plot. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916205/seaborn-heatmap-move-colorbar-on-top-of-the-plot) but since I am plotting a [big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997662/how-to-plot-heatmap-for-high-dimensional-dataset) heamap when I use the first answer i.e., `cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec=False,location="bottom")` , the result is as provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6fxxbl7mbt9yjr/corr_matrix03.png?dl=0).

Also, if the third answer is applied i.e., `cbar_kws = {'orientation':'horizontal'}` , the result is as provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxgjqpaxsie5je6/corr_matrix01.png?dl=0).

My heatmap plot with colorbar on the right is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtb0ugfo0rk6aq8/corr_matrix0.png?dl=0). I just want to change it's position, so it's length should be unchanged. The second answer increased it's length.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second result looks to have the colorbar at the bottom only!

Comment: @svr_sum yes but it is too bigger than the heatmap plot.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. The code is the first answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997662/how-to-plot-heatmap-for-high-dimensional-dataset . Besides, some part of the data set is also here: https://www.kaggle.com/shebrahimi/financial-distress

Comment: One thing to note is that if you use a figsize of `(24, 18)` with a vertical colorbar, you should probably use a figsize of  `(18, 24)` when using a horizontal colorbar, because the heatmap itself is square.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. I tried figsize of `(18,24)`. It could deal with the issue of the second solution but unfortunately, the issue is not resolved for the first solution.

Comment: So what's wrong with using the second solution then?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks. the second solution is ok. Could you please let me know if it is possible to plot a big picture like this as 12 separate pictures (each separate picture would show some part of the big picture)? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534480/get-legend-as-a-separate-picture-in-matplotlib). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the relation between this question and the linked question. Maybe it's better to ask a new one, with a clear description of what you want to do.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're welcome. Sorry, I asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417398/how-to-plot-a-big-picture-as-some-separated-pictures).

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering the figsize of the graph like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))  #Try and set the fig size accordingly.   
sns.heatmap(df1,linewidths=.5,ax=axis) #df1 is your dataframe.
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't change my `figsize` because my data set includes a lot of features.