# "RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure" when creating a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I intend to create a new legend in a separate figure for elements already plotted in another figure.

The following solution is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279532/7042795), but it fails for `PolyCollections`, e.g. produced by `fill_between`.

```py
doesntwork=True

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Here I am creating a figure and saving it to a png file

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( [0,1], [1,0], label='item 1')
if doesntwork:
    ax.fill_between([0,1], [2,1], y2=[1.5,0.5], label='item 2')
ax.legend()
fig.savefig('image.png')


# Here I want the legend stored in a separate png file ...

# ... create a new figure for this purpose
fig_leg = plt.figure(figsize=(1.5, 0.8))
ax_leg = fig_leg.add_subplot(111)

# ... draw the legend
ax_leg.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels(), loc='center')

# ... turn of the axis and save to file
ax_leg.axis('off')
fig_leg.savefig('legend.png')
```

When doing without `fill_between`, by setting `doesntwork=False`, all is fine and `legend.png` is produced showing the legend.

With `doesntwork=True` I get:

```
RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

How can I get this to work with `doesntwork=True`?